# How to post on friends wall on facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am using facebook php sdk. And i have integrated facebook open graph on my app. 
I want to post on friends wall using open graph like in this image.
I have captured this image wall post from another app and i want to make same post like this.

Also i want to make a action link like "Get App".
when user clicks on Get app. My app should open on a new tab.

I read many docs. And they say it is not possible to post on friends wall using open graph and i tried $facebook->api('/$firend_id/feed) but it posts a link on friends wall.
I dont want link i want to post a gift to friends wall .

Please suggest me how can i do it?

Regards,
Krishna [image: post form other's app]

Comment: You can not publish Open Graph actions to/for anyone else but the your app user. But this does not look like an Open Graph action to me anyway, but just like a normal link posted to someone else’s wall. The link itself probably has parameters, so that the app will know who gave a give to whom when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using hit and trial method.

```
$attachment = array(
             'message' => $d['giftmsg'],
            'name' => 'You have recived a gift voucher for a '.$dd['title'].'!' .'',
            'link'=>'https://thevoucherlink.com/redirect.php',
            'description' => " Please click on the link to claim your gift card. Do it soon! This promotional card is valid for a limited time.. <center>&nbsp;</center> The Voucher Link allows facebook users send gift vouchers from local businesses to their friends",
            'picture' => $im,
            'actions'=>array('name'=>'Get Voucher','link'=>'https://thevoucherlink.com/redirect.php')
        );  


        try {
             $t=    $facebook->api('/' . $_POST['friend_id']. '/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            $err= $exc->getTraceAsString();
        }
```

You can make same post using these parameters on post.

Thank you for your answers..

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the attachment, I think you meant "How to add action links to wall posts?" See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actionlinks/

Comment: I found it was not a open graph thing. It was facebook post using graph api. http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed